# inconsistent schema when reading parquet and exporting from Vertica

Tags: python, export, parquet, vertica, pyarrow

I've noticed weird behaviour when exporting data from Vertica and trying to read it later with parquet (python).
Let's say I want to have table dump to parquet:

```
EXPORT TO PARQUET (directory = '/data/table_name') over (partition by event_date) 
AS select * from table;
```

it gives me next structure:

```
/data/table_name
 - event_date=2019-01-01
 - event_date=2019-01-02
 - event_date=2019-01-03
...
```

Then I'm trying to read it with pyarrow:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
df = pq.read_table('/data/table_name')
```

But I'm getting an error of inconsistent schema:

```
ValueError: Schema in partition[event_date=0] ./event_date=2019-01-01/84087de6-node0001-139759025940222.parquet was different.
user_id: string
event_id: int64
event_name: string
install_date: int32
event_date: int32
site_id: string

vs

user_id: string
event_id: int64
event_name: string
install_date: int32
site_id: string
```

How come?

P.S. 
If I read each dir separately - it works fine.

```
df1 = pq.read_table('/data/table_name/event_date=2019-01-01')
df2 = pq.read_table('/data/table_name/event_date=2019-01-02')
df3 = pq.read_table('/data/table_name/event_date=2019-01-02')

df1.schema == df2.schema == df3.schema
> True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the partition column (`event_date`) from the export query:

```
EXPORT TO PARQUET (directory = '/data/table_name') over (partition by event_date) 
AS SELECT user_id,
          event_id,
          event_name,
          install_date,
          site_id
FROM table;
```

Comment: this is the way I've resolved this issue. However, it is totally inconvenient as I can not just do select * ...